# delete a rabbitmq binding with an empty source_name

Tags: rabbitmq

details see below:

```
root@beb46cb4b84f:/# rabbitmqctl list_bindings
Listing bindings for vhost /...
source_name     source_kind     destination_name        destination_kind        routing_key     arguments
        exchange        topic_task_worker_manufacture   queue   topic_task_worker_manufacture   []
        exchange        topic_task_worker       queue   topic_task_worker       []
topic_task      exchange        topic_task_worker_manufacture   queue   manufacture.node        []
topic_task      exchange        topic_task_worker       queue   parse.step      []
```

I have two bindings with an empty source_name as the output. Now, How can I delete them?

I try this command but failed:

```
root@beb46cb4b84f:/# rabbitmqadmin delete binding source="" destination_type="queue" destination="topic_task_worker" properties_key="topic_task_worker" -u xxxx -p xxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 1185, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 524, in main
    method()
  File "/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 767, in invoke_delete
    (obj_type, uri, upload) = self.declare_delete_parse(DELETABLE)
  File "/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 787, in declare_delete_parse
    (uri, upload) = self.parse_args(self.args[1:], obj)
  File "/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 839, in parse_args
    uri = uri_template.format(**uri_args)
KeyError: 'source'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source in your case is `topic_task`. That's the right command

```
rabbitmqadmin delete binding source="topic_task" destination_type="queue" destination="topic_task_worker" properties_key="topic_task_worker"
```

Edit:

Each queue is bound by default to the AMQP default exchange and can't be removed by protocol. So you can't do this: `delete binding source=""`

Comment: I found there are always two bindings that share the same source_name, and destination_name but have different routing_key when I create a new binding. Is there exists any document I can read?

Comment: I think that you referer to the default binding to the AMQP default queue. it can't be removed.  Each queue is bound to the AMQP default, that' by the protocol